# How to install gdlib-config on Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: apt, software-installation

According to the [Ubuntu manuals](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/gdlib-config.1.html) the command `gdlib-config` exists on Ubuntu 16.10. See also [this blog post](http://blogs.perl.org/users/gabor_szabo/2012/07/what-package-provides-gdlib-config-in-your-distribution.html).

However, if I do

```
apt-file search gdlib-config
```

I get no results. I want to install a package that contains `gdlib-config`. ( This file is required in order to install a given Perl module )

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what `gdlib-config` does, but I've worked around similar issues by creating wrapper scripts for `pkg-config`

Answer (score 16):

I ran into much the same problem today when I tried to use cpan to install the Perl module GD. It failed because it could not find package gdlib. I found I needed to install libgd-dev

```
apt-get install libgd-dev
```

After this I was able to install the GD module and also had /usr/bin/gdlib-config

Comment: Thank you, your suggest fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

If the above did not work for you, you can [install libgd by hand](https://comery.github.io/2018/08/15/An-error-when-install-perl-module-GD/)[modified for sudo]:

> ```
> wget https://github.com/libgd/libgd/releases/download/gd-2.2.5/libgd-2.2.5.tar.gz
> tar zxvf libgd-2.2.5.tar.gz
> cd libgd-2.2.5
> ./configure 
> make
> sudo make install
> make installcheck
> ```